# Spark-Cassandra connector taking too long to read the data from Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I wanted to archive the data from Cassandra to Amazon S3, and for that i am using DataStax [SparkCassnadraConnector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector). I am using the help of CQLContext to query cassandra as mentioned in the below code. I have also mentioned the mean partition size of my cassandra which is also decent. Read few links on SO and came to know to increase the `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb`. But still this job is taking too long to read the data and finally store it on Amazon S3. Is there something wrong which i am doing here?

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "CASSANDRA_HOST_IPS").setAppName("ExportCassandraDatajob")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "128")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","ACCESSKEY")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey","SECRETKEY")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem") 

val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
csc.setKeyspace("KEYSPACE_NAME")
val dFArchive = csc.sql("select * from SOME_COLUMN_FAMILY where partitionkey in  ('key1' , 'key2' ...so on) " )
dFArchive.rdd.saveAsTextFile("S3_PATH",classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
```

Partition size in cassandra columnfamily :

```
Compacted partition mean bytes: 173509526
```

Comment: I'm not sure if where predicate gets passed down to Cassandra in csc. You might be doing a full table scan. Try upgrading to DSE 5 and use sqlContext or use joinWithCassandra and RDDs for better performance.

Comment: This will push down but not in a good way. You will end up doing a single Partition with a single query where the entire query will sit on the coordinator.

Comment: What should be best way to do it in a distributed manner?